# Scanning from file line until integer in C

Tags: c, io, string-parsing

I have problem with scanning a string from a file until integer value appears. 
If I try `fgets(str,30,file);` it scans everything in a single line of file, including the integer.

Example of file:

```
Audi 2014
Wall Street 1995
The number of words used in one line may vary 9999
```

Integer is always last but number of words before value is not always the same, so code like `fscanf(file,"%s %s %d", str1, str2, &integer);` does not work as well. 
My intention is to scan everything until the integer value in string and than scan the integer separately. 
Any ideas ?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you want the integer value or the text too?

Comment: Both. I need the text part in separate string and integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bare bones C, no fancy stuff. It will work if your data has the format you described, i.e. space separated words in a text file with the number of each line right before the newline character, and each line starts with at least one word that is not your number. Size of the buffer can change as you like, it will only affect performance.
Also, your file needs to have at least one line in the format you describe.

```
FILE *f;
char bf[2048];
char *p, *p1;
int line, i, num;

f = fopen("mydatafile.txt", "r");
if (f)
{
    line = 0;
    while (!feof(f))
    {
        fgets(bf, sizeof(bf), f);
        p1 = bf;
        p = strchr(bf, '\n');
        while(p)
        {
            *p = 0;
            i = 0;
            while (isdigit(p[--i])) ;
            num = atoi(p+i+1);
            p[i] = 0;
            printf("line %d: %s  number = %d\n",++line, p1, num);
            p1 = p+1;
            p = strchr(p1, '\n');
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

For your sample data the output is:

```
line 1: Audi  number = 2014
line 2: Wall Street  number = 1995
line 3: The number of words used in one line may vary  number = 9999
```

Answer (score 2):

Read with fgets and do a single pass through the string `while(!isdigit[str[i++]);` to get to the starting position of number. Then `atoi` from that position and put a `'\0'` there

```
fgets(str,30,file);
int i = 0;
while(str[i]!='\0' && !isdigit(str[i]))
    i++;
int num = atoi(str + i);
str[i] = '\0';
```

Now the number is in `num` and the string before it is in `str`

Comment: If the number is beyond 26 places you have a problem

Comment: fgets includes the '\0' too. So if the number starts at 27th place you take only 3 digits. Even worse, if the number is even further, you take only text.

Comment: That's only because the array size is limited. Just increase array size. That limit will always be there whatever be the size of the array

Comment: The code must be agnostic of the size. It must work for all situations. The OP said *The number of words used in one line may vary*. Having a specific number for an array is not a solution. Think of another example. You set a big number like 100, but fgets scans two lines or three... You get the first but lose the others.

Comment: So what method do you suggest if you need to read the characters before the number as well for use. The OP says he needs both the integer value and the text before it. `scanf("%*[^0-9]%d", &num)` will ignore all the text.

Comment: I am not suggesting a solution but rather pointing a flaw in your method. If a had a solution, I whould have posted it as an answer.

Comment: It's not a flaw. I need to know the possible limit on the size of the string if I need to read a string so that I can allocate memory for the string. That's a constraint unless I go for alternative methods such as using a dynamic array / linked list implementations of string but that's simply making it too complex.

Comment: IMO, limiting the size of the input buffer to some sane and _generous_ amount like 100 here is a _good_ design practice.  An excessively long line is itself a candidate error and should be detected as an error.  I recommend a buffer 2x max expected line size.

Answer (score 1):

Read the whole line and do your own parsing, or use fscanf. Pattern "%29[^0-9] %d" or something alike.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need those numbers in your input lines, you could using the following code to achieve your goal

```
    while (scanf("%*[^0-9]%d", &num) == 1) {
```

That `*` indicates that the non-digit characters before the number will be ignored.